# Story about people with specific mindset are killed off

Tags: story-identification

I read this story a few years back so the details are kind of fuzzy. This is about a society (not ancient) where the people with artistic mind set are killed off secretly (people would think that it was some disease) to preserve the purity of growth of humankind by government or some hidden force. Some people find that out and tried to fight back.

Can someone identify the story for me please?

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Please do take a look at the guide otherwise your question is just going to be closed as "Too broad"

Comment: Not a problem, it's what I'm here for :)

Comment: There is also [Futuristic dystopian story about a boy who gets killed for being too intelligent](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/76390/4495), but I'm sure that's not it. There's no secrecy.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/239728/teen-fantasy-book-series-about-a-world-where-people-who-showed-creativity-could (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 4):

### [The Unwanteds by Lisa McMann](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9917879-the-unwanteds)

> **When Alex finds out he is Unwanted, he expects to die.** That is the way of the people of Quill. Each year, all the thirteen-year-olds are
>   labeled as Wanted, Necessary, or Unwanted. Wanteds get more schooling
>   and train to join the Quillitary. Necessaries keep the farms running.
>   **Unwanteds are set for elimination.**  It’s hard for Alex to leave behind his twin, Aaron, a Wanted, but he makes peace with his
>   fate—until he discovers that instead of a “death farm,” what awaits
>   him is a magical place called Artimé. **There, Alex and his fellow
>   Unwanteds are encouraged to cultivate their creative abilities and use
>   them magically.** Everything Alex has ever known changes before his
>   eyes, and it’s a wondrous transformation.

*(emphasis mine obviously)*

They have a war at the end of the book. The main character uses paperclip shurikens.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure if their elimination of the creative people is responsible for the name "Quilitary" or a signal that they're still pretty imaginative without them.

Comment: I am sure there was no twins and the "unwanteds" are killed off secretly. But thanks for helping :)