# Teen fantasy book series about a world where people who showed creativity could learn magic, and were killed for it

Tags: story-identification, books

The first book starts where the main character shows creativity, and is sent presumably to his death. He then ends up in a secluded area run by a caretaker where they learn to use their creativity and art as magic.

The two sides go to war, one led by the main character and the other by his twin on the other side. In later books, they learn that they live on an island in a chain, and multiple books deal with those other islands. They learn from someone from our world that they live in the Bermuda Triangle, and they also wrap around to the other side of the island chain if they go to the end via a giant waterfall.

Some random things in there are magical sentient whiteboards and statues. A sequel series was released recently, detailing the children and their adventure. That's about all I can recall, can't remember names of anything.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this book?  Do you recall any details about the cover, or how long it was?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Unwanteds by Lisa McMann.

> When Alex finds out he is Unwanted, he expects to die. That is the way
> of the people of Quill. Each year, all the thirteen-year-olds are
> labeled as Wanted, Necessary, or Unwanted. Wanteds get more schooling
> and train to join the Quillitary. Necessaries keep the farms running.
> Unwanteds are set for elimination. It’s hard for Alex to leave behind
> his twin, Aaron, a Wanted, but he makes peace with his fate—until he
> discovers that instead of a “death farm,” what awaits him is a magical
> place called Artimé. There, Alex and his fellow Unwanteds are
> encouraged to cultivate their creative abilities and use them
> magically. Everything Alex has ever known changes before his eyes, and
> it’s a wondrous transformation. But it’s a rare, unique occurrence for
> twins to be divided between Wanted and Unwanted, and as Alex and
> Aaron's bond stretches across their separation, a threat arises for
> the survival of Artim that will pit brother against brother in an
> ultimate magical battle.

And I remember that the Unwanteds were those who had creativity.

Does this answer your question?